# Saga transient exceptions logged as error

Tags: masstransit

I'm on Masstransit 6.2.

I'm using Marten for saga storage and serilog for logging.

My saga often gets database concurrency exceptions but can be recovered using retry/re-delivery.
However these exceptions are logged as "SAGA:" errors along with the "R-RETRY" warnings.

I found this old issue https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/626, apparently this has been addressed? Is there anything can be done to downgrade these errors or stop logging them?

Comment: There is definitely some redundant logging happening, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed this is fixed in 6.2.2.